# useLazyQuery returns old data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

Why that code is working improperly ? I change profileId and nothing happened, useLazyQuery is still returns the old data.

```
    const [profile, setProfile] = useState<Profile>(null);
    const [getProfile, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery<Data<'profile', Profile>, { id: string }>(PROFILE, {
      ssr: false,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      getProfile({
        variables: { id: profileId },
      });
    }, [getProfile, profileId]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!loading && !error && data) {
        setProfile(data.profile);
      }
    }, [setProfile, data, loading, error]);
```

I am using:

```
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set fetchPolicy to:

```
fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
```